# sample covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, covariance, system-identification

Suppose two covariance function estimators, with the same formula except for a coefficient. Then make two sample covariance matrix(SCM) from each of the functions. Why should these matrices differ in negativeness or positiveness feature? To be clear $R=[R_{i-j}]$ should be non-negative definite(positive semi-definite) but $\tilde{R}  =[\tilde R_{i-j}]$ is not necessarily non-negative definite. 
$$y(t)=\phi(t)\theta$$
 $$R_{k}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^{N-k}y(t)y^T(t+k)\quad R_{-k}=R_k^T\quad k\ge 0$$
 $$\tilde{R}_{k}=\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{t=1}^{N-k}y(t)y^T(t+k)\quad \tilde R_{-k}=\tilde R_k^T\quad k\ge 0$$ 
The SCM is built by the following formulla.
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}R_0&R_1&\cdots&R_{N-k}\\
R_1^T&R_0&\cdots& R_{N-k-1} \\
\vdots\\
R_{N-k}^T&\cdots&&R_0 \end{bmatrix}$$
They are used in system identification.
[main problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrVWr.png)

Comment: What is the matrix here to be clear ? Please make your question non ambiguous, thanks!

Comment: @Ezy Clear enough?

Comment: Much better! Now i understand the question :)

Comment: And R is dimension NxN ? In other words you let k run up to N-1 ?

Comment: y is $n\times 1$ so R is $nN\times nN$ and yes we let k run up to $N-1$

Comment: Ok cool thx for precision. Then i understood correctly and answered below. For N=2 you can see the matrices can differ already

Comment: I meant every $y(t)$ is $n×1$

Comment: Ok, so there are y(t) for $t\in 1..N$ and each y(t) has N rows. Got it. But it does not change the conclusion of my answer

Answer (score 0):

For $N=2$ and $y(0)=(1,-1)/\sqrt{2}$ and $y(1)=(-1,-1)/\sqrt{2}$ you see that the first matrix has determinant 0 while the second one has determinant $>0$ so they have different signature.

Comment: please check the changes I have made in the question.

Comment: I updated my answer. Going forward you need to make questions non ambiguous

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for the proof of first one not an example only! :)

Comment: There is no proof because the claim is wrong. I gave counter example

Comment: Seems that your counter example is wrong since $R_0$ has determinant 0.5 and $R_1$ has determinant  0 and matrix $R$ is nonnegative which is not contradict what has mentioned in the stated problem.

Comment: Ok then please make your question clear. As of now i cannot see a mathematical statement yet, just some ambiguous phrase which is quite confusing. Once you make a clear mathematical statement then i'll try answer your question

Comment: This problem is in dr. soderstrom book (system identification) chapter 5 problem 1

Comment: I dont have this book. You would do yourself a favor by formulating your question following the problem or just copy/scan  the formulation of the problem

Comment: I have added the image of the question as the main problem